# Ember Brocfile does not import JS and CSS files

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an Ember CLI application. I am trying to add the BeatPicker jQuery datepickers to my application using `app.import()` in the Brocfile but they don't seem to be getting included in vendor.js and vendor.css. I installed [BeatPicker](https://github.com/nagarjun/BeatPicker) through Bower and see that the files are in bower_components folder. I am also using retina.js and that seems to get compiled into vendor.js. I am not sure why BeatPicker is not getting compiled. Here is a copy of my Brocfile:

```
/* jshint node: true */
/* global require, module */

var EmberAddon = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-addon');

var app = new EmberAddon({
  babel: {
    includePolyfill: true
  }
});

// Retina.js
app.import('bower_components/retinajs/dist/retina.min.js');

// BeatPicker
app.import('bower_components/BeatPicker/build-0.1.3/css/BeatPicker.min.css');
app.import('bower_components/BeatPicker/build-0.1.3/js/BeatPicker.min.js');

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

Even the paths are correct. What am I missing?

Comment: I dont see any issue with your brocfile. Did you restart the server ?

Comment: @selvagsz I did. I even tried running `ember build`. Only the retina.js file seems to be getting compiled. The vendor.css file is empty. When I search vendor.js, I can't find the other scripts.

Comment: What version of the cli are you on?

Comment: @Kitler Here's what `ember --version` returns:

version: 1.13.6      
node: 0.12.7      
npm: 2.13.2      
os: darwin x64

Comment: I tried downloading BeatPicker from http://act1gmr.github.io/BeatPicker/docs.html and imported in Brocfile. But I don't find any issues

Comment: @selvagsz Did you install BeatPicker through Bower? The irritating thing is that now, I am also trying moment.js and even that is not getting imported.

Comment: ```
app.import('bower_components/BeatPicker/css/BeatPicker.min.css');
app.import('bower_components/BeatPicker/js/BeatPicker.min.js');

```
the above was the path I used in the Brocfile

Comment: http://bower.io/search/?q=BeatPicker I don't find any bower packages :(

Comment: @selvagsz I also could not find the Bower package. That's why I forked their repository on GitHub and created a release: https://github.com/nagarjun/BeatPicker. Can you please try using that and checking if it works? I also don't know if it is an issue with BeatPicker since no other scripts are getting compiled. I even tried moment.js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88096/discussion-between-selvagsz-and-nagarjun).

Comment: `Brocfile.js` was deprecated in favor of `ember-cli-build.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since v1.13 of ember-cli, `Brocfile.js` has been deprecated in favor of `ember-cli-build.js`. See the [transition doc](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/TRANSITION.md) for more info on why they made the change.